# Как правильно преобразовать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов типа

```
[{
    name: "6", 
    value: 6
}, 
{
    name: "7", 
    value: 7
}, 
{
    name: "8", 
    value: 8
}]
```

Как мне из него получить массив типа `[6,7,8]`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Это уже массив
2. `arr.map(x => x.value)`